# ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis error + java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have this procedure in sql:

```
PROCEDURE classificacao(csr OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, campeonato number, ttime VARCHAR2) AS
  sql_text VARCHAR2(600);
  BEGIN
    sql_text := 'SELECT ESTPRAT7.totaljogos('''||campeonato||''', '''||ttime||'''), ESTPRAT7.totalvitorias('''||campeonato||''', '''||ttime||'''), ESTPRAT7.totalempates('''||campeonato||''', '''||ttime||
    '''), ESTPRAT7.totalderrotas('''||campeonato||''', '''||ttime||'''), ESTPRAT7.totalpontos('''||campeonato||''', '''||ttime||'''), ESTPRAT7.aproveitamento('''||campeonato||''', '''||ttime||''') FROM DUAL';
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_text);
    OPEN csr FOR sql_text;
  END classificacao;
```

and it executes correctly. But when I try to execute in my JAVA program, keeps raising this error

Here is the java code:

```
OracleCallableStatement pesquisa = 
        (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("{ call EstPrat7.classificacao( ?, "+n+", ? )}");
        pesquisa.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        pesquisa.setString(2, time);
        pesquisa.execute();
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the whole sql call. I see nothing faulty here, it's probably a wrong parameter in an unexpected format/with an unexpected symbol.

try

```
 System.out.println(pesquisa );
```

if that doesn't give you the sql output(and if I remember right the oracle driver didn't), you can use https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/ to see the sql output (or see the oracle query history).

Comment: mistake i made was query string was getting formed as "columnnameAND" instead as "columnname AND" your answer helped me @schoen